# hibernate cannot find field in derived class (generics suspected)

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, dao

I have a class Fruit, a class Banana that extends Fruit and a class YellowBanana that extends Banana. YellowBanana has got a field called "tasty". If I'm trying to access "tasty" in a query based on generics I'm getting the following exception:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [tasty] on this ManagedType [Fruit]
```

A simplified version of the code is this:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class Fruit implements Serializable
    {
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public class Banana extends Fruit
    {
    }

    @Entity
    public class YellowBanana extends Banana
    {
       private boolean tasty = false;
    }

    public abstract class GenericDao<T extends Fruit>
    {
       public List<T> getObjects(Filter filter /* some criteria passed here */)
       {
          EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
          CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(getPersistentClass());
          Root<T> root = query.from(getPersistentClass());

          List<Predicate> predicates = getFilterQueryRestrictions(root, builder, filter);
         if (predicates != null && !predicates.isEmpty())
            query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

          return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
       }

       private Class<T> getPersistentClass()
       {
          return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
       }
    }

    public class BananaDao extends GenericDao<Banana>
    {
        @Override
       protected List<Predicate> getFilterQueryRestrictions(Root<Banana> root, CriteriaBuilder builder,
         Filter filter)
       {
          List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

          if (filter.forceTasty)
              // The exception is on the following line on root.get:
              restrictions.add(builder.equal(root.get("tasty"), 1));

          return restrictions;
       }
    }
```

As you can see my goal is to have a generic DAO that does all the CRUD operations for Fruit objects. For derived entites I am creating the actual DAO classes (BananaDao in this example). getPersistentClass() returns the actual generic type. This generic way of the DAO has been working beautifully so far with all operations until I passed a derived instance (YellowBanana in this example).

Of course this is only a short example. Fruit in reality is the base class of all my entites (there are many). How can I make Hibernate find a mapping for the "tasty" field?

Answer (score 0):

The `tasty` attribute is not defined on `Banana` like your DAO code expects.  You've only defined it on the extended class, `YellowBanana`, which is the only entity type where it is applicable in your hierarchy.

If `tasty` is to be made available to both `Banana` and `YellowBanana`, you should define it either as part of your `Banana` entity or as part of the mapped superclass type and your code will work just fine.

Comment: But the "bananas" table that Hibernate is generating does contain the "tasty" field so Hibernate is finding that field correctly! When I pass a yellowBanana instance to that DAO Hibernate knows that it's a derived object and it stores the value of the "tasty" field. That's why I don't understand why it's unable to find it when I pass it to root.get().

Comment: Then the code in your question should be changed to reflect your existing entity configurations because you specified `tastey` on `YellowBanana` and not on the `Banana` super type.

Comment: I just tested the code as it appears in your question, that code fails for the reason which I presented.  If the code mirrors the prior comment, it works.  I believe you should review your code once more.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The tasty attribute is part of the question or problem definitíon I want to solve so I cannot put it somewhere else. If I did I wouldn't be able to work with class hierarchies. So the solution I finally ended up with is to create a DAO class for YellowBanana, too.

Answer (score -1):

You should add getter and setter for that field, and also map it using annotations

```
@Column(name="tasty")
private boolean tasty = false;

public boolean isTasty(){
return tasty;
}

public void setTasty(boolean tasty){
this.tasty = tasty;
}
```